# Formatting Java code in WordPress posts, like in Eclipse

Tags: wordpress

I am about to write some posts which has some Java code, and I would like to format it properly by coloring the Java keywords. Like in [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29).

I am looking for some recommendation for a theme / plugin to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Chili code formatter](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-chili/) is a good WordPress plugin to do that.

Alternative link: *[WP Chili](http://webscripts.softpedia.com/script/Modules/WordPress-Plugins/WP-Chili-48730.html)*

You could have some other plugins with [this page](http://speckyboy.com/2009/02/19/12-wordpress-plugins-to-display-and-highlight-code-within-your-blog/) or this [other one](http://faq.wordpress.com/2007/09/03/how-do-i-post-source-code/).

However, it has not been updated for since 2010. Maybe you should use much recent one like the [WP Code](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-code/) plugin.

It seems new versions of WordPress have already [included the support of code posting](http://en.support.wordpress.com/code/posting-source-code/). It is very interesting for me too, LOL.

Comment: Re *"new versions of WordPress have already included the support of code posting"*: Yes, but for a self-hosted WordPress blog, you have to install and activate the plugin *["SyntaxHighlighter Evolved"](https://wordpress.org/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/)* (by Alex Mills - 46 search hits if left out) before it works.

Comment: I really coud not tell that when I have posted these answer, in 2012, because I have never used Wordpress. I am coding from php frameworks, especially zf1=>zf3, code igniter, modx, laravel, etc.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like it's rather standard nowadays:

```
[code language="css"]
   Your code here
[/code]
```

As described [here](https://en.support.wordpress.com/code/posting-source-code/) by WordPress itself.

Comment: Is this also avaible in community edition? I could not find the plugin itself nor does this work for me?

Comment: Yes, I was able to make it work on my community edition Wordpress account. Also, its not a plug-in. As the answer mentions, its built-in into Wordpress by default.

Comment: Yes, but for a self-hosted WordPress blog, you have to install and activate the plugin *["SyntaxHighlighter Evolved"](https://wordpress.org/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/)* (by Alex Mills - 46 search hits if left out) before it works.