# How can I add code formatting to WordPress?

Tags: html, wordpress

I am developing an tutorial blog in WordPress, and I have the intention to show some code blocks in the pages/posts I write.

Is there a plugin to show the code blocks in the pages (something like [Sublime Text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text) style would be better).

Comment: Does this answer your question? *[Formatting Java code in WordPress posts, like in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12233843/formatting-java-code-in-wordpress-posts-like-in-eclipse)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the settings of code blocks in the pages you can use the 
**[Crayon Syntax Highlighter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/crayon-syntax-highlighter/)** plugin.
To change the setting you can see the plugin instruction.

in post use that button from tinymce and add code
[image]

or in html use this as sample

```
<pre class="lang:php decode:true">
  $x="I Am Lemon Kazi";
  $y=explode(" ",$x);
  echo "Total Number of words in $x is ".count($y);
</pre>
```

Follow the instructions of these plugins.  here is a screenshot of code block.
[image]

Comment: its weird i see nothing changed after adding this plugin after adding this code. [php]
Sample CodeRuby
// A sample class
class Human {
private int age = 0;
[/php]

Comment: See there I used that plugin http://www.it4gen.com/single-connection-string-in-form-application/   I updated my answer please check.

Comment: I found the problem. sorry. apparently if you do not add wp_footer(); in your theme's footer, nothing will work and thats why I was saying it is weird.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially follow the instructions in [wordpress.org/support/article/writing-code-in-your-posts/](https://wordpress.org/support/article/writing-code-in-your-posts/)

The solution conjured up by the actual WordPress developers is at [wordpress.org/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/](https://wordpress.org/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/). You install the plugin and then wrap your code with `[code]` shortcodes.

Comment: It moved to https://wordpress.org/support/article/writing-code-in-your-posts/